# React Conditional Rendering: How can hide the Button when the array "Name" has more than two values?

Tags: reactjs

How can hide the Button when the array **"Name"** has more than two values?

Code sandbox link
https://codesandbox.io/s/patient-platform-3zs7li?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have updated your code in codesnadbox according to your requirement.

https://codesandbox.io/s/peaceful-platform-dvdy5e?file=/src/App.js:0-325

```js
import "./styles.css";

const data = [
  {
    name: ["person_one"]
  }
];

const Active = ({ name }) => {
  return (
    <>
      {console.log(name)}
      {name?.length < 2 && <button>BTN</button>}
    </>
  );
};

function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <Active name={data[0].name} />
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```